# How to fix doxygraph error when generating Drupal UML from XML?

Tags: 7

I need to document my project and I'm using doxygen for that. The documentation has been created and works perfectly, what I need now is to generate the class diagrams of my entire project code base.

I've doxygen generate an XML version of the source code documentation, [doxygraph](https://code.google.com/p/doxygraph/) claims that once I have that I can generate my class diagrams with ease. I've tried the example included in the library and it does a pretty good job.

I've tried to generate my project class diagrams but I get the following error:

```
Attribute (type) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation failed for 'Doxygen::XML::Compound::Linkedtext' with value undef at reader Doxygen::XML::Compound::Param::type (unknown origin) line 8
Doxygen::XML::Compound::Param::type('Doxygen::XML::Compound::Param=HASH(0xb4026f0)') called at doxygraph/doxygraph/lib/Doxygen/XML.pm line 228
Doxygen::XML::_member_parameters('Doxygen::XML::Compound::Memberdef=HASH(0xb3f57b8)') called at doxygraph/doxygraph/lib/Doxygen/XML.pm line 197
Doxygen::XML::_do_operation('Doxygen::XML=HASH(0x8e85ab0)', 'addressfield_views_handler_field_country', 'Doxygen::XML::Compound::Memberdef=HASH(0xb3f57b8)') called at doxygraph/doxygraph/lib/Doxygen/XML.pm line 165
Doxygen::XML::_do_class('Doxygen::XML=HASH(0x8e85ab0)', 'Doxygen::XML::Compound::Compounddef=HASH(0xb3f4e94)') called at doxygraph/doxygraph/lib/Doxygen/XML.pm line 136
Doxygen::XML::parse_compound('Doxygen::XML=HASH(0x8e85ab0)', 'docs/xml/d7/d76/classaddressfield__views__handler__field__country.xml') called at doxygraph/doxygraph line 17
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You mention class diagrams a couple of times there - which classes are you referring to? Are they part of custom modules or are you referring to Drupal 7's handful of core classes?

Comment: I'm actually referring to the classes generated for my entire project code base, i.e. for Drupal core itself and all the (contributed) modules, themes and libraries I have installed.

Comment: Gotcha - you are aware the majority of core code, a lot of contrib module code and pretty much all themes are procedural in nature? i.e. no classes? (unless this is a D8 site). For that specific error, it might be because none of the methods in [addressfield_views_handler_field_country](https://github.com/phase2/openpublic-drops-7/blob/master/profiles/openpublic/modules/contrib/addressfield/views/addressfield_views_handler_field_country.inc) are documented

Comment: Yes Clive, I know D7 is not Object Orient, and hence no classes. In truth, I would never want to have a Class Diagram for my own needs but the client I'm working for is demanding I provide one. I don't think I'm going to pursue it any longer since, the doxygen documentation is pretty much comprehensive. A very interactive set of images have been generated as well, so I guess that would be more than enough. Thanks for the ideas!